# Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10

Tags: jupyter-notebook

I am trying to open Jupyter Notebook on Windows 10 and I am having trouble. I already downloaded and installed it. When I click on the Jupyter Notebook icon in my start menu, a black terminal appears titles Jupyter Notebook. Then I just disappears after that like nothing happened.

Things I have done to combat this issue:

- I downloaded VirtualBox with Ubuntu and downloaded the Linux version there. However, it stated it could not be installed since it was not a 64-bit system. I tried to download the 32 bit version but the download always failed.

  - Next I add the the link http://localhost/* to my Kapersky Internet anti-virus exceptions page thinking it was preventing Jupyter from opening. This didn't work and turning off the firewall completely also didn't work.

Any help would be great help!

Comment: Don't use the icon, run from the command line. https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @cricket_007, you have to run jupyter first before opening notebooks.  From the terminal, run:

```
> jupyter notebook
```

After a few seconds, a server will start.  If your [dashboard](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/running.html#running) does not open automatically, point your browser to `http://localhost:8888`.  *Note: if you installed Jupyter with [Anaconda](https://www.continuum.io/downloads), there should be a shortcut you can click to do all of the above.*

The dashboard will point to your default working directory.  Place notebooks in this directory or navigate to your notebook's directory to open it through the browser.

Should you wish to change the default working directory, see more on [configuring notebook paths](https://jupyter.readthedocs.io/en/latest/projects/jupyter-directories.html#data-files) in the docs.

Answer (score 2):

There are several ways to use jupyter notebook under windows, especially windows 10 professional.

My favorite way is the lovely ubuntu subsystem of windows 10. You can install it directly from the app store, which is free for all windows 10 users. Then install jupyter notebook from the subsystem:

```
apt install python3-dev python3-pip 


pip3 install jupyter
```

or you can just do 
    apt install python3-dev python3-pip jupyter

then just run

```
jupyter notebook
```

open any windows browser, copy paste the localhost.... thing from ubuntu terminal
then you can using jupyter notebook with a linux core.